# What is the case screw length and thread pitch for the 2010 MacBook 13" Model 7,1?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I have a 2010 MacBook 13" Model 7,1. It has recently gotten some upgrades and one of the screws wandered off and was eaten by a grue.

What length and thread pitch are the eight screws holding the bottom panel on to the laptop body on this model?

These screws and panel are shown [in this iFxit tutorial](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+Lower+Case+Replacement/1665). I see that these are 4mm screws. I would like to know the screw size so that I can just order them as generic screws in my next McMaster-Carr delivery.

Metric screws are measured by the outside diameter of the threads, the spacing between threads and the length as in `Ma-b X c`. iFixit tells me the length is 4mm. So I have `Ma-b X 4mm`. I need to know `a` and `b`. I suspect that this may be a non-standard or atypical screw size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Measuring the ones on my 2015 Air they seem to be M2 x 0.4mm

Comment: Completely different year, completely different model..!

Comment: But I did at least attempt to answer the question, and went to the trouble of taking a screw out to measure it. 
The point is that they seem to be standard ISO metric coarse threads. 0.4mm pitch is standard for M2.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which screw you lost.  It's important to know because there are a number of different screws specific to that model:

| Length | Head Type & Size | Dimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3mm | Phillips #0. | Head: 2.75 mm. dia. |
| 3mm | Phillips #0. | Head: 2.75 mm. dia. |
| 4mm | Phillips #0. | Head: 2.75mm dia. |
| 6.25mm | Phillips #000 | Head: 4mm. dia. x .5mm thick |
| 3.25mm | Phillips #000 | Head: 4mm. dia. x 4mm thick |
| 11mm | Phillips #00, with Shank | 2.2mm dia. x 2mm len. Head: 3.2mm dia. x .5mm thick |
| .25mm | Phillips #00, with Shank | 2mm dia. x 3.75mm len. Head: 3.2mm. dia. x .5mm thick |
| 5.2mm | Phillips #00, with Shank | 2.3mm dia. x 3.5mm len. Head: 3.2mm. dia. x .5mm thick |
| 11mm | Phillips#00 in the middle of the case | Head: 5mm dia. x .75mm thick |
| 14.5mm | Phillips #00 | Head: 5mm dia. x .75mm thick |

Source:  [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Core_2_Duo)

Your best bet is to browse through the repair guides on iFixit, identify the screw that you are missing then search for it online.  However, if it's just one screw, you will probably be just fine.

Comment: Wrong model its this one: https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Unibody_Model_A1342 and I am missing one of the screws shown here: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+Lower+Case+Replacement/1665